# WordPress Warning Support

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I cannot access my website admin panel. It shows the following warning

```
Warning: Cannot modify header information – headers already sent by (output started at /home/filmymik/public_html/wp-content/themes/jarida/functions/theme-functions.php:1) in /home/filmymik/public_html/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1210
```

Yet, the website is working fine. What could be the issue?

Comment: Can't anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You most likely have leading white space in your theme-functions.php that is referenced in the warning. This leads to PHP starting the body output, and WP cannot set cookies for you, so you cannot authenticate to wp-admin.

Solution: remove the whitespace before the first opening `<?php` or `<?`.

Comment: I tried the option yet the problem was not resolved.

Comment: Was there whitespace? Is there anything else?

Comment: There was a dot (.) before <?php in /home/filmymik/public_html/wp-content/themes/jarida/functions/theme-functions.php

Comment: Remove that dot! Sorry, whitespace is the usual culprit, but anything before the opening `<?php` will lead to this result.

Comment: I remove that much before. There is nothing before <?php. Yet not working

Comment: And it is the exact same error message, the line number hasn't changed? What does the complete line 1 of that file look like?

Comment: Yes exactly same message.First few lines are as :<?php
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

# Get Theme Options

/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
function tie_get_option( $name ) {

 $get_options = get_option( 'tie_options' );
 if( !empty( $get_options[$name] ))

  return $get_options[$name];

 return false ;
}

Comment: Can't anyone help me?